# Click event on menu in javafx

Tags: user-interface, javafx, menubar, mouseclick-event

I want to make a programme which we can change the scene if users click the menu items.

[Simple image of the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3y8w.png)

For example if u click the settings in the menubar, another scene in the same window will show up and you can change the settings of the programme.

Note:My Menu doesn't have any menu items.just menubar.

What did i tried so far ?
Adding some buttons to HBox and assaign it to top of the BorderPane.It does work but didnt look like like menu.Tried to make it seems like menu with CSS but didnt work.

What is the problem?
Problem is click handler on main menu does not work.
if i assign click event handler to from begginning button it does work but not on "Settings" menu.

And wondering what is the best way to implement this idea?

Comment: Menus don't generate events if they are empty (unfortunately). Probably your best bet is to add some buttons (or maybe just labels?) to a `HBox` (or `ToolBar`) and style them to appear as menus, as you describe. I recommend trying that and posting a specific question with your attempt to make that work, if you can't get it working the way you want.

Answer (score 2):

Its been more than a year but here is a simple solution for `Menu` to make **clickable**:

```
<MenuBar>
        <Menu>
            <graphic>
                <Label fx:id="yourId" text="Your Text here" onMouseClicked="#mouseClickedEvent"/>
            </graphic>
        </Menu>
</MenuBar>
```

Answer (score 1):

Below are sections of a previous project of mine. MenuItem is in a different class and I call a method in main to switch scenes.

I have two pages selection and information, both have their own container and scene and stylesheet. The selection page is the initial one displayed at start and I switch information page.

```
settingsMenuItem.setOnAction(e -> {
    e.consume();
    Launcher.selectionPage();
});
```

My main class:

```
public class Launcher extends Application {

    private static FlowPane selectionPane;
    private static BorderPane infoPane;
    private static Scene selectionScene, infoScene;
    private static Stage theStage;
    private static String selectionCSS;
    private static String informationCSS;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        //Global reference needed to switch scenes in another method.
        this.theStage = primaryStage;

        //Declares resources, in this case stylesheet. Declared here to be applied in another method 
        selectionCSS = this.getClass().getResource("/views/SelectionStyle.css").toExternalForm();
        informationCSS = this.getClass().getResource("/views/InformationStyle.css").toExternalForm();

        //Initial page setup
        selectionPane = new SelectionPage();
        selectionScene = new Scene(selectionPane, 500, 500);
        selectionScene.getStylesheets().add(selectionCSS);

        //Stage setup
        primaryStage.setScene(selectionScene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    //Changes page
    public static void informationPage(String starSign) {

        infoPane = new InformationPage();
        infoScene = new Scene(infoPane, 500, 270);
        infoScene.getStylesheets().add(informationCSS);
        theStage.setScene(infoScene);
    }
}
```